# Store variable for specific request on beforeRemote('create' and use it on afterRemote('create'

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to store variable for specific request on beforeRemote('create' and use it on afterRemote('create'.
i know that i can store the variable on the model class variable but i am afraid that it will be shared across requests.

for example:

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, unused, next) {
   // Here i want to store a variable like:

   this.storedValue = "xxx";
}
```

and then, use it here:

```
MyModel.afterRemote('create', function(ctx, unused, next) {
console.log(this.storedValue);
}
```

is the this.storedValue that i will declare in the model will be static or instance model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, unused, next) {
   // Here i want to store a variable like:

   ctx.hookState.storedValue = "xxx";
}

MyModel.afterRemote('create', function(ctx, unused, next) {

  const storedValue = ctx.hookState && ctx.hookState.storedValue; 
  console.log(storedValue);
}
```